# How to install pip (python) to user without root access

Tags: apt, software-installation, permissions, python

I'm trying to install pip (python installer) to my username since I don't have root privileges and can't just `sudo apt-get install python-pip`.

So what I've done is just `easy_install --user pip`. That installs it to `.local/bin` apparently but then when I call it like so:

`pip install --user astropy`

It says that pip is not currently installed.

I have limited knowledge of linux and of the system I'm using (NX connection to a machine at my university). I know I should be able to do this!

Comment: If `easy_install` is not available, you can install `pip` to local with  `wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py && python get-pip.py --user`

Comment: Here is the up-to-date version of the above method: `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python get-pip.py --user`

Comment: Get this error:   OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip'

Comment: @ablmf - did you add the `--user` when running `python get-pip.py --user` ?

Comment: @qed 's comment should be the accepted answer

Comment: If you have no `wget`: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

Comment: What if I have activated a virtual environment (venv or virtualenv) and then use pip? Shouldn't it then install to the folder that is associated by venv/virtualenv with the active (activated) environment and NOT to ~/.local/bin/ ? I thought the idea is that you have multiple environments comparable to the `Ruby Version Manager` and `Gemsets` where you can both install packages to the global namespace of the `RVM` or to specific `Gemsets` such that it allows you for example to make use of multiple version combinations of packages etc. in the gemsets... When Python, despite an active...

Comment: ... virtual environment for pip to install packages to, installs everything into `~/.local/bin` then this is very comparable to the `@global` namespace of the `ruby version manager` and hence it breaks any intention to have separate sets of plugins and separate sets of versions maybe of those sets. Asked differently: How do I force pip to only install into the activated virtual environment folder and not into `~/.local/bin` ? Thanks

Answer (score 25):

I hope I'm right and the problem is with your `PATH`, try this

You can add this to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

If you don't know how, you can just execute this line in a Terminal:

```
echo "PATH=\$PATH:~/.local/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

You can also check what's in your `PATH` by typing in the Terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc` for the change to make effect!

Answer (score 4):

This may be related. How to install python from source on a remote machine without root access.

### Installing Python 3.6 (works with any version per say)

1. Get the official download link from python.org website ([example](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.9/Python-3.6.9.tgz))
2. Download the python source release and get the folder readied for installation from source.

   ```
   wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.9/Python-3.6.9.tgz
   tar zxfv Python-3.6.9.tgz
   find ~/inflated_location/Python-3.6.9/Python -type d | xargs chmod 0755
   cd Python-3.6.9
   ```
3. Install from source

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=~/inflated_location/Python-3.6.9/Python
   make
   make install
   ```
4. Export the path variable

   ```
   nano ~/.bashrc
   export PATH=~/inflated_folder/python/Python-3.6.9/:$PATH
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

Now you have python3.6 installed for logged in user and can be invoked now using command `python`

### Installing py packages

The easiest way that I have followed is

```
python -m pip install <package-name> --user
```

[Reference](https://randomwalk.in/python/2019/10/27/Install-Python-copy.html)