# pip doesn't know of apt-get installed packages

Tags: apt, python, pip, ipython

On a quite fresh Ubuntu 16.04, I'm installing ipython with pip, as a user installation. Pip itself was installed from the `python-pip` Ubuntu package (8.1.1), and so are some dependencies like pygments or setuptools (20.7.0).

My question: is it normal that when doing a user installation with pip, apt-get installed packages are not detected? Is is a known bug?

This is the command I run (as a user, not as root):

```
$ pip install ipython
```

→ I get the download of many packages from PyPI, including setuptool (27.3.0) and Pygments (2.1.3). I don't think it's a version issue, since ipython requires `setuptools>=18.5` only. Incidentally, I also get a complaint that pip should be updated to latest version (8.1.2).

Even more intriguing, when I run the same command again, I get the same installation process (only difference: wheels are cached). Instead, I would expect pip telling me that ipython is already installed.

Notice that there is no doubt that ipython (version 5.1.0) is indeed installed in my `~/.local` directory, and it runs well (the only adjustment I had to make was adding `~/.local/bin` to the `PATH` variable in `~/.bashrc` as mentioned in a [dedicated question](https://askubuntu.com/a/363314/598354)).

It seems to me that something is wrong with the way pip detects apt-get installed packages, but I cannot figure out what. Am I missing something obvious?

If it can help the diagnostic, this is the Python module path (modelica is the username):

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/modelica/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/omniORB/COS', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

Comment: The latest version of pip is 8.1.2, so the `python-pip` package is indeed slightly outdated. You can ignore it if the pip you have still works. However, if you do plan to upgrade it, I would suggest using a virtualenv to do it. As for running `pip install ipython` a second time, I am surprised pip doesn't just tell you ipython is already installed; it definitely does say that for me in a virtualenv. Can you try again to make sure this particular behavior is reproducible?

Comment: To move things forward, I've reported this behavior as a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1628432 I've expanded the title a bit because pip doesn't recognize *any* preinstalled packages, not just apt-get installed packages.

Comment: Thanks @edwinksl for your feedback. The behavior of repeated installation of packages already installed is reproducible (on this VM!) and it's not just ipython. However, I'm not in a virtualenv. Finally,  as I mentioned in the bug report, I don't feel comfortable updating pip with a broken pip.

Answer (score 1):

> is it normal that when doing a user installation with pip, apt-get installed packages are not detected? Is is a known bug?

I just dived into pip's code and found that pip's `list` command filters a list of packages provided by [pkg_resources.WorkingSet()](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/67f534d3e36bd91e5e8f03615886d200786fb4b4/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L612), which in turn gets its entries from `sys.path`. The result is that `pip --list` will also list system packages installed by APT. But that doesn't mean pip should manage this packages.

Pip and APT work differently, starting with where they install to: pip installs globally to `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` or `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages` (depending on version) and locally to `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`, while APT based tools install globally to `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages`.

This oddity relates to a [design decision by Debian developers](https://wiki.debian.org/Python#Deviations_from_upstream) in order to avoid conflicts between packages provided by them and packages obtained by other means ([this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages#9388115) pointed me in the right direction).

So no, it isn't a bug that pip lets you install packages to `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` even if a package is already installed in `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages`.

---

Lets see with your ipython example. I also have installed it previously with APT:

## DEB Package

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep ipython
ipython                     install

$ dpkg -s ipython | grep Version
Version: 2.4.1-1

$ dpkg-query -L ipython
(...)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
(...)
/usr/bin/ipython
(...)
```

## Pip Package

```
$ pip show -f ipython
(...)
Name: ipython
Version: 5.3.0
(...)
Installer: pip
(..)
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Files:
  ../../../bin/ipython
```

*Note: `../../../bin/ipython` ends up being `/usr/local/bin/ipython`.*

The command `whereis` gives me both IPython instances:

```
$ whereis -b ipython
ipython: /usr/bin/ipython /usr/local/bin/ipython
```

And I could still get a third IPython on `~/.local` if I wanted!

---

> Even more intriguing, when I run the same command again, I get the same installation process (only difference: wheels are cached). Instead, I would expect pip telling me that ipython is already installed.

This seems odd indeed. Here's what I have observed so far: when a package has already been installed by pip locally, it appears to install every  time (it always outputted "Successfully installed {package}"), but it really seems to just alter the packages dist-info. For example, I tried installing lxml locally (either with `pip install lxml` or `pip install --user lxml`) a couple of times:

Compare the timestamp from the first lxml installation with the one after the last lxml "installation":

1.

```
myusr@myhost:~$ ls -al .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages | grep lxml
drwxrwxr-x  5 myusr mygroup  4096 feb 20 15:01 lxml
drwxrwxr-x  2 myusr mygroup  4096 feb 20 15:01 lxml-3.7.3.dist-info
```

2.

```
myusr@myhost:~$ ls -al .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages | grep lxml
drwxrwxr-x  5 myusr mygroup  4096 feb 20 15:01 lxml
drwxrwxr-x  2 myusr mygroup  4096 feb 20 15:03 lxml-3.7.3.dist-info
```

However, when one tries to install a package globally, pip **does** show a message:

`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
python3 -m pip install ipython
```

For Me Working