# How can I record the screen (or screencast) in text mode?

Tags: virtual-console, screencast

Basically I want to capture the process of installing a driver in Ubuntu so I can watch it later.

There are screen capture applications such as SimpleScreenRecorder, but they won't work in text mode because there is no display driver when I stop LightDM.

There is also `fbcat` which lets us take screenshots in textmode, but I wonder if there is something I can use to screencast when I switch to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Asciinema

If you want to go youtube style, look at [asciinema](http://asciinema.org). You can install it using:

```
sudo apt install asciinema
```

To get a more recent version if you are not on 18.04 yet, you can either use this ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:zanchey/asciinema
sudo apt update
sudo apt install asciinema
```

or use the pip method:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install asciinema --user
```

(see also: [How to install pip (python) to user without root access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363300/how-to-install-pip-python-to-user-without-root-access#363314))

Now start a recording session using

```
asciinema rec output.cast
```

which will drop you in another shell. Recording will last until you exit this shell. You can play the result using:

```
asciinema play output.cast
```

**Beware!** If you start `asciinema rec` without providing an output file name, it will default to uploading the recorded session to asciinema.org and returning just a URL. You can cancel before, but it's easy to miss that point.

Comment: wow! this was simple for me. works like a charm.

Comment: @SebastianStark: Thanks alot, I chose this over the `ttyrec` which by the way works prefectly fine just becasuse of the Sharing & embedding features Asciinema offers. that part was very neat. By the way I guess more people would enjoy this if you also add the pip installation method :)

Comment: Note that this fails to pick up command error output generated in a virtual console. This can be inconvient if you're executing the command in the virtual console *in order to* see that output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `script` to save everything printed or typed in the terminal.

From the `script` manpage:

**DESCRIPTION**

```
   script makes a typescript of everything displayed on your terminal.  It
   is useful for students who need a hardcopy  record  of  an  interactive
   session  as  proof  of  an  assignment.
```

To use script:

`script termout.txt`

This will save all the screen contents to "termout.txt". Type `exit` to stop `script`

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer made me find what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

[ttyrec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttyrec) is a `tty recorder`. Recorded data can be played back with the included `ttyplay` command. `ttyrec` is just a derivative of `script` command for recording timing information with microsecond accuracy as well.
It can record `emacs -nw`, `vi`, `lynx`, or any programs running on `tty`.
It is widely used for example in the NetHack community for storing game replays.

It is similar to the `script` command, but also allows for **pausing**, **slowing down** or **speeding up playback**. It can also **stream** the recording on the network and be used to transfer files with `uudecode`.

> **Usage**
>   **Recording**
>
> ```
>   % ttyrec
>   (In the executed shell, do whatever you want and exit)
>
>   % ttyrec -e command
>   (command specified by -e option will be executed)
> ```
>
> **Playback**
>
> ```
>   % ttyplay ttyrecord
> ```
>
> -s2 option makes the playback speed doubled. With -p option, you can peek another person's ttyrecord in real time. Have fun!
>
> You can change the speed while playback by the following key strokes.
>
> "+" or "f" to speed up the playback twice "-" or "s" to speed down the
>   playback twice "1" to change the playback to the normal speed

**Note**:
You can end the recording by typing `exit`. and also you can specify a filename after `ttyrec`. if you don't specify one, it will create one.

**Recorders/players**
original [ttyrec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttyrec#cite_note-homepage-1) (Unix)
Term::[TtyRec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttyrec#cite_note-2) (Perl)
Term::[TtyRec::Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttyrec#cite_note-3) (Perl)
Tie::[Handle::TtyRec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttyrec#cite_note-4) (Perl)
[termrec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttyrec#cite_note-5)  (Win32, Unix)

**Playback only**
[TTYPLAYER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttyrec#cite_note-6) (Java)
[IPBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttyrec#cite_note-7) (Unix)