# Recording TTY screen on Ubuntu

Tags: tty, virtual-console, desktop-recording

How can I record my tty2 screen?

I tried OBS-Studio, launched OBS-Studio in tty1 (GNOME), and started recording. But it shows a black screen when I switch to tty2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I record the screen (or screencast) in text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024091/how-can-i-record-the-screen-or-screencast-in-text-mode)

Comment: I'm using tty not terminal, I really don't like guis

Comment: No, it records commands, etc. But I need to record as a video. To publish in youtube